# How to do a subtraction between &ndarray::Array1<f64> and &mut Array1<f64>?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust, rust-crates

I find it impossible to do a subtraction between an immutable array reference and a mutable one using the [ndarray crate](https://crates.io/crates/ndarray):

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate ndarray;

use ndarray::Array1;

fn main() {
    let a: &Array1<f64> = &array![3.0, 2.0, 1.0];
    let b: &mut Array1<f64> = &mut array![1.0, 1.0, 1.0];
    let c = a - &b.view();          //   This compiles
    let d = a - b;                  //   This fails to compile
}
```

The error message I get is:

```
let d = a - b;
          ^ no implementation for `f64 - &mut ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
```

I don't understand what these two types mean, but is there any special reason why this is not implemented?

Answer (score 2):

The [`Sub` trait in `ndarray::ArrayBase`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.11.2/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#impl-Sub%3C%26%27a%20ArrayBase%3CS2%2C%20E%3E%3E-1) is not implemented for `&mut` arguments (it is for immutable references to other arrays). It is not needed because the right-handed value should not be modified. The second operand is a `&mut Array<A, D>`, and it ends up being one of the cases where type weakening into an immutable reference does not happen automatically. Still, you can explicitly reborrow the value:

```
let a: &Array1<f64> = &array![3.0, 2.0, 1.0]; 
let b: &mut Array1<f64> = &mut array![1.0, 1.0, 1.0]; 
let c = a - &b.view();
let d = a - &*b;
```

This assumes that `a` and `b` were obtained elsewhere. In fact, you can make these variables own the arrays instead:

```
let a: Array1<f64> = array![3.0, 2.0, 1.0]; 
let mut b: Array1<f64> = array![1.0, 1.0, 1.0]; 
let c = &a - &b.view();
let d = &a - &b;
```

Answer (score 1):

The full error message is:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `f64: std::ops::Sub<&mut ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:15
   |
10 |     let d = a - b;
   |               ^ no implementation for `f64 - &mut ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Sub<&mut ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>>` is not implemented for `f64`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Sub<&mut ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>>` for `&ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `&mut ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>: ndarray::ScalarOperand` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:15
   |
10 |     let d = a - b;
   |               ^ the trait `ndarray::ScalarOperand` is not implemented for `&mut ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Sub<&mut ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>>` for `&ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<f64>, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
```

The first error message is quite obscure for me but the second is more enlightening:

> the trait `ndarray::ScalarOperand` is not implemented for `&mut ndarray::ArrayBase

The reason of this error is that Rust does not perform coercions when matching traits: If there is an impl for some type `U` and `T` coerces to `U`, that does not constitute an implementation for `T` (copied directly from [the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nomicon/coercions.html))

Without entering into ndarray internals, this is a minimal example reproducing the same problem:

```
trait MyShape {}

fn foo<T: MyShape>(x: T) -> T {
    x
}

impl<'a> MyShape for &'a i32 {}

fn main() {
    let mut num = 1;
    let arg: &mut i32 = &mut num;
    foo(arg);
}
```

Result:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&mut i32: MyShape` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
12 |     foo(arg);
   |     ^^^ the trait `MyShape` is not implemented for `&mut i32`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <&'a i32 as MyShape>
   = note: required by `foo`
```

Comment: May I ask how you copied your error messages? They lost whitespace before the `|` (they should all be lined up). I've seen this a bunch, but don't know what causes it.

Comment: I copied output from terminal into visual studio code, I selected all and added a tab (4 spaces) to the selected text.